# Advice to implement an app that calculates the best route

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So i want to make an app for my University Thesis where the user can add different locations from one city. This app will calculate the best route based on distance and time (distance from one location to another, and time spend in traffic and in queues at these locations).
Basically, for example if I wanna see Sagrada Familia, Park Guell and Casa Battlo in the same day, my app will show me where to go first, the best location at a certain time, where there is the minimum queue of people and where to go next, so I can see all these locations in the same day and spend minimum to no time in traffic and on queue.

My questions is, I want to develop my code on the Travelling Salesman Problem or on VEHICLE ROUTING PROBLEM, and I wanted to ask you if these 2 are appropiate for my problem or should I think myself a new code. I am kinda new to developing an app all by myself and I don't know where to begin... Hope you understand and you can help me.

Comment: If "queues at these locations" does not change over time, you could go for Travelling Salesman since the queueing time can be ignored since you must quere no matter in which order you meet the locations.

Comment: I want to make it as much accurate as I can so the queues at he locations will change. In this case should I use the VHP?